# I need to re-mount the shared folder everytime my host folder has new files or changes in Virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, shared-folders, xubuntu

I work with a Windows 7 host and a Xubuntu guest. 
Everytime my shared folder in Windows has new files or changes, I have to hit sudo mount -t vboxsf ...
Why's that? Can I automate it somehow?

Is there any other more efficient way for folder sharing between Host and Guest systems?